# How to add blog directory in front of single WordPress post?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site set up and I would like the blog directory to show in the URL when viewing a single post:

`mysite.com/blog/my-first-post` instead of `mysite.com/my-first-post`

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Working : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WO_AwRKDt0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a Home page and a Blog page (make sure the blog page is named "Blog" and the slug is "blog")
2. Go to Settings>Reading
3. Choose Static Home Page
4. Set your home page and blog page
5. Go to Settings>Permalinks
6. Create a custom structure: `/blog/%postname%/`

From the WordPress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Your_Blog_Appear_in_a_Non-Root_Folder

Comment: I've been doing this for all my WP sites, but I'm encountering a problem. Other plugins that generate virtual pages, such as Testimonials, and Events, all have 'blog' infront of them in the URL. Is there a way I can set the permalinks to just be post-name, and only apply /blog/ when viewing single blog posts?

Comment: It will conflict with other post types. For example: if you have post type called Services and the slug is service, the URL will be then `/blog/service/{post_slug}`

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is old, but somebody may benefit from my answer:

There are two parts: adding rules so /blog/article-slug and /blog/paged/ points to the proper URLS and also modifying all slugs to the new links:

```
function THEME_SLUG_posts_add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $new_rules = [
        'articles/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&paged='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
        'articles/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    ];
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'THEME_SLUG_posts_add_rewrite_rules');

function THEME_SLUG_posts_change_blog_links($post_link, $id=0){
    $post = get_post($id);
    if( is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'post'){
        return home_url('/articles/'. $post->post_name.'/');
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'THEME_SLUG_posts_change_blog_links', 1, 3);
```

Here is the example of adding /articles/ before blog posts title. Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules, for example by saving the permalink settings