# How to add '/blog' in front of wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress, url, post, url-rewriting

I want to add '/blog' in front of my all blog posts. I changed this from **'Setting -> Permalinks -> Custom Structure'** but it adds '/blog' to all custom posts as well. I am using lots of custom posts and custom categories.

I found some solutions [here](https://www.quemalabs.com/blog/how-to-add-blog-in-front-of-your-url/). In this solution all working fine but there is no solution to remove '/blog' from custom category url.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. Just add `'rewrite'   => array( 'with_front'    => false ),` this into custom category arguments array.

**IMPORTANT**: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select **Settings -> Permalinks** and just click Save Changes without any changes.

See below Eg.

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'rewrite'   => array( 'with_front'    => false ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
);
register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while, but I wrote a small plugin for this problem. https://jaimemartinez.nl/blog/2023/06/04/prefix-blog-posts/

This add the prefix, but only to the Post "post type".
And it add a Archive page for you, but you can disable that.

The code can be found here https://github.com/jmslbam/wp-post-url-prefixer.

This is a copy of the code with comments in it. I got feedback to post the full code here, for when the link might not work anymore.

```
<?php
/**
 * WordPress Post URL prefixer
 *
 * @package     WP_PUP
 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name:     Post URL prefixer
 * Plugin URI:      https://jaimemartinez.nl/plugins/wp-post-url-prefixer/
 * Description:     Prefix only your post URL and not your tag and category permalinks & have a automatic blog posts archive
 * Author:          Jaime Martinez
 * Author URI:      https://jaimemartinez.nl
 * Text Domain:     wp_pup
 * Domain Path:     /languages
 * Version:         0.2.0
 */

/**
 * Get the singular prefix of the post Post type.
 */
function wp_pup_get_singular_url_prefix() {
    return \apply_filters( 'wp_pup_singular_prefix', 'blog' );
}

/**
 * Get the archive slug of the post Post type.
 */
function wp_pup_get_archive_url_prefix() {
    return \apply_filters( 'wp_pup_archive_slug', 'blog' );
}

/**
 * Set prefix value as slug of post and it's archive.
 *
 * @props https://stackoverflow.com/a/24635076/557225
 */
function wp_pup_register_post_type_args( $args ) {
    $prefix = \wp_pup_get_singular_url_prefix();

    if ( empty( $prefix ) ) {
        return $args;
    }

    $args['rewrite'] = array(
        'slug' => $prefix,
    );

    $page_for_posts = (int) \get_option( 'page_for_posts' );

    if ( $page_for_posts === 0 ) {
        $args['has_archive'] = \wp_pup_get_archive_url_prefix();
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wp_pup_register_post_type_args', 15, 2 );

/**
 * Change permalink of post to contain our new prefix when calling `get_the_permalink()`
 */
function wp_pup_pre_post_link( $permalink, $post ) {
    $prefix = \wp_pup_get_singular_url_prefix();

    if ( empty( $prefix ) ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    if ( $post instanceof WP_Post && $post->post_type === 'post' ) {
        return '/' . $prefix . $permalink;
    }

    return $permalink;
}
add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'wp_pup_pre_post_link', 15, 2 );

/**
 * Add rewrite rule
 *
 * @props https://stackoverflow.com/a/63312315/557225
 */
function wp_pup_posts_add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $archive           = wp_pup_get_archive_url_prefix();
    $singular          = \wp_pup_get_singular_url_prefix();
    $new_rules         = array(
        $archive . '/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),
        $singular . '/(.+?)/?$'           => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'wp_pup_posts_add_rewrite_rules' );

/**
 * Change post type archive link when calling `get_post_type_archive_link`.
 */
function wp_pup_post_type_archive_link( $link, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type === 'post' ) {
        return \trailingslashit( \trailingslashit( \get_home_url() ) . \wp_pup_get_archive_url_prefix() );
    }

    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_archive_link', 'wp_pup_post_type_archive_link', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add our custom post type archive to the Yoast Breadcrumb when there is no page selected at the "Reading settings > Posts page".
 */
function wp_pup_wpseo_breadcrumb_links( $crumbs ) {

    // If there is a page selected on the "Reading settings > Posts page", then let Yoast do it's magic.
    if ( (int) \get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) !== 0 ) {
        return $crumbs;
    }

    $post_type_object = \get_post_type_object( 'post' );

    // If you the Posts don't have an Archive - e.g. FSE custom template with custom Query block - then do not.
    if ( ! $post_type_object->has_archive ) {
        return $crumbs;
    }

    $_crumbs[] = $crumbs[0]; // Save our home crumb in a tmp array.
    unset( $crumbs[0] ); // delete it.

    // Add our custom post type archive link.
    $_crumbs[] = array(
        'url'  => \get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' ),
        'text' => ( $post_type_object->labels->name ),
    );

    // Loop the remaining crumbs and re-add them to the tmp array to have a correct index numbering.
    foreach ( $crumbs as $crumbs ) {
        $_crumbs[] = $crumbs;
    }

    return $_crumbs;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'wp_pup_wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 20 );
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34497214)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I added a copy of the code in the answer.